# Fundamental system of $x'=Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear DE $$x'=Ax=\begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\4&-1\end{pmatrix}x,$$ and its general solution $\varphi(t)$. One method would be computing $$\exp(tA)=\begin{pmatrix} (2t+1)e^t & -te^t\\4te^t&(1-2t)e^t\end{pmatrix}$$ and then for any initial value $(x_1,x_2)$ we'd have $\varphi(t)=\exp(tA)(x_1,x_2)$ as a general solution.

Question: I thought that another way to obtain this solution is to just write it as a linear combination of the vectors from the fundamental system. $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$ so a fundamental system would be $$\left\{v_1=e^t(1,0),v_2=e^t(t,1)\right\}$$but obviously $\varphi(t)\neq x_1 v_1+x_2 v_2$. Why is that? Is my fundamental system wrong?

Comment: You have changed your basis, so that must be reflected in the fundamental system. If $A= VJV^{-1}$, then $e^{At} = V e^{Jt} V^{-1}$.

Comment: So the basis I given would be a basis for $x'=Jx$ where $J$ is the jordan form from your comment?

Comment: You are using (presumably) the Jordan form above, so $V$ would be chosen to get the Jordan form.

Comment: I've edited my comment: For $x'=Jx$ the fundamental system would be $\{v_1,v_2\}$ as given above. But then what is the upside of this? I need the transformation matrix $V$ one way or the other, neither way saves time here.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What's unclear?

Comment: You have found a solution in another basis, as I pointed out in my first comment. Yes, the transformed system will be $y'=Jy$ in the basis that produced the Jordan form. That addresses the question asked above. I don't know what you mean by upside.

Comment: By upside I meant that my initial intention here was to find a way that the easiest to execute on paper. But it seems that both are the exact same workload.

Comment: OK, but that is not what your question is about.

Comment: If you want to save work, you can compute $\exp(tA)$ without finding an eigenbasis by setting $N = A-I$ and use the facts that $N^2=0$ and that $I$ and $N$ commute.